# CMakeLists.txt file Error, How did this error come about

Tags: android, c++, cmake

The error occurs at this path
/cxx/RelWithDebInfo/1k2r4e66/obj

but I did not generate the 'obj' folder

```
> Task :app:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a] FAILED
C/C++: CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
C/C++:   No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
C/C++:   contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
C/C++:   code such as
C/C++:     project(ProjectName)
C/C++:   near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().
C/C++:   CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
C/C++:   line.
C/C++: This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
C/C++: CMake Warning at /Users/bakbeom/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:416 (message):
C/C++:   An old version of CMake is being used that cannot automatically detect
C/C++:   compiler attributes.  Compiler identification is being bypassed.  Some
C/C++:   values may be wrong or missing.  Update to CMake 3.19 or newer to use
C/C++:   CMake's built-in compiler identification.
C/C++: Call Stack (most recent call first):
C/C++:   /Users/bakbeom/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:55 (include)
C/C++:   .cxx/RelWithDebInfo/1k2r4e66/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/3.18.1-g262b901/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
C/C++: ninja: error: 'src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java4.so', needed by '/Users/bakbeom/work/HWST/build/app/intermediates/cxx/RelWithDebInfo/1k2r4e66/obj/arm64-v8a/libnative_opencv.so', missing and no known rule to make it
```

I don't confirm that the Cmake files are correct. it's here

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)
project(HWST)

add_library(lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java4.so)

add_library(libMNN SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libMNN PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libMNN.so)

find_library(log-lib log)

include_directories(cpp/includes/)
set(HEADER_FILES cpp/detector.h cpp/FaceCubePlus.h cpp/recognizer.h)
add_library(native_opencv SHARED  cpp/native_opencv.cpp ${HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries(native_opencv lib_opencv libMNN ${log-lib})
```

[image]

Comment: So the problem is `set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java4.so)` this expects the `libopencv_java4.so` file to be an existing file in specified location. If it does not exist you can not continue. Is `${ANDROID_ABI}` properly set to match the folder structure you have downloaded / installed?

Comment: @drescherjm yes it Looks fine

Comment: So the CMakeLists.txt you are using is in a folder that also contains the folders `src` and `cpp`

Comment: @drescherjm yes.

Comment: @drescherjm  Maybe the path is wrong, I will try   https://github.com/leadrien/opencv_native_androidstudio/issues/11

Comment: You could change `set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java4.so)` to `set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java4.so)` and see if that fixes the issue by using an absolute path instead of a relative path.

Comment: While some CMake **functions** accept relative paths and handle them relatively current `CMakeLists.txt`, a **property** should always contain an **absolute** path, relative paths are not allowed. The thing is that CMake handles build-related properties only at the end of the configuration process, when any information about "current `CMakeLists.txt`" is lost.

Comment: I will do so later. The day software developement job got in the way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a project name to the CMakeLists.txt

Add this at the top of your CMakeLists.txt but after cmake_minimum_required().

```
project(YourProjectName)
```

Comment: I added the project, but still have the same error,

Comment: The actual error is in the last line.

Comment: Looks like it can't find the file                                                                          1k2r4e66/obj/arm64-v8a/libnative_opencv.so

I only have this path
1k2r4e66/arm64-v8a/libnative_opencv.so

Comment: I don't quite understand how this obj folder is generated

Comment: @bakboem Possibly it's made by CMake in some earlier step. And it actually wants the file `src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java4.so`, but it can't find it nor it knows how to make it.

Comment: Are you sure this was the correct `CMakeLists.txt` file? Perhaps you should use one from a higher level in the folder tree. And perhaps that higher level CMakeLists.txt creates the missing file. I ask that because the root CMakeLists.txt should have a `project()` in the file. Any reasonable opensource library will not make the mistake of omitting that.

Comment: @drescherjm I added CmakeList file, can you help me?